# create subset of the records where value=1. Ignore the other values as they carry no information

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have following data frame:

[image]

I need to create one another dataframe by ignoring 0 values. For example in the 3rd row first column value is 3D and for this, the actual value is Manufacturing because it has 1 in it. The same rule applies for all the rows. At the last I need two columns in the resultant data frame with categroy_list and value associated with that.

Was going through pandas doc and it might be possible via melt() but I am not able to do that. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are looking for...

You can use `update` after creating dataframe from (index,col) pairs:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat_list':list('ABCDE'),
                   'col2':[0]*5,
                   'col2':[0,0,1,0,1],
                   'col3':[1,1,0,0,0],
                   'col4':[0,0,0,1,0]})

# index,col values where df==1
new = pd.DataFrame(list(df[df ==1 ].stack().index)).set_index(0).rename(columns={1:'cat_list'})
df.update(new)

  cat_list  col2  col3  col4
0     col3     0     1     0
1     col3     0     1     0
2     col2     1     0     0
3     col4     0     0     1
4     col2     1     0     0
```

or are you looking to merge?

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat_list':list('ABCDE'),
                   'col2':[0]*5,
                   'col2':[0,0,1,0,1],
                   'col3':[1,1,0,0,0],
                   'col4':[0,0,0,1,0]})

# index,col values where df==1
new = pd.DataFrame(list(df[df ==1 ].stack().index)).set_index(0).rename(columns={1:'cat_list'})
df.merge(new, left_index=True, right_index=True)

  cat_list_x  col2  col3  col4 cat_list_y
0          A     0     1     0       col3
1          B     0     1     0       col3
2          C     1     0     0       col2
3          D     0     0     1       col4
4          E     1     0     0       col2
```